# Autocomplete para formulários

Tags: javascript, html, formulário, testes

Conhecem alguma ferramenta da Web no Chrome ou Firefox que autocompletam os formulários com texto aleatório para testes? Eu tenho um form de 35 campos e cada vez que submeto para testes, tenho que completá-lo novamente.

Comment: Monta o formulário já preenchido para testar, e tira antes de publicar... `<input type="text" name="nome" value="Fulano de Tal">` ou faz uma funçãozinha que crie uma string aleatória, ou pegue um valor de um array...

Comment: Bem lembrado, posso deixar os values setados pra não precisar preencher toda hora @jader. Você poderia elaborar uma resposta com as possíveis soluções, assim eu dava a melhor resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando jQuery da pra fazer uma funçãozinha para preencher todos inputs quando a pagina estiver pronta:

```
<script>        
$(document).ready( function() { 
   $("input").each(function(){ // percorre todos elementos "input" do documento
        $(this).val("textoQualquerSoParaTestes"); // atribui o valor genérico para os campos
   });
});
</script>
```

A não ser que você tenha que usar `values` específicos, isso deve servir.

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer algo utlizando JFiller:

- http://www.ajaxblender.com/jfiller.html

Ou extensões para o Chrome:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo

Ou a solução da função citada acima, fazendo um switch para os tipos de input e gerando dados aleatórios de acordo com o tipo de dado e regras de validação.